# node.js promises in for-loop

Tags: node.js, pdf, merge

I'm trying to achieve merging of multiple files (and creation of PDF documents if the database result returns multiple elements with non-empty 'json' field).

Now merging occurs only once and merges the first element with `element['json'] != ''` with itself.

Merging logic is:

all PDF's are laready created, except of that we'll create next

if an element contains some JSON, create a PDF

if an element doesn't contain JSON, merge it to the previous PDF

Maybe pushing all promises into array and passing them to Promise.all() helps? Really stuck now.

```
app.get("/api/generatePDF", jsonParser, function(req, res) {

var saveFilename, savePath;
var idDocument, idPatient, idDoctor, idItem;
var orientation = "";
var url = req.route.path;
var tbl = "";
var html = "";
var hasTables = 0;
console.log(req.query.json);
var savedJSON = JSON.parse(req.query.json);
var flag = 4;
var id_inventory = parseInt(savedJSON['id_inventory']);
var request = new sql.Request();
var files = new Array();
var badFiles = new Array();
var options = "";
var mergeNeeded = parseInt(savedJSON['param']);
if (mergeNeeded == 1) {
    flag = 14;
}
var cnt = 0;
var output = parseInt(savedJSON['output']);
var mergedName = savedJSON['merged_name'];
var numRows = 0;
var idSpec = mergeNeeded;
if (id_inventory == 0) {
    var pid = savedJSON['id_patient'];
    var idDocType = savedJSON['id_doc_type'];
    idSpec = savedJSON['id_spec'];
    flag = 10;
    request.input('id_patient', sql.Int, pid);
    request.input('id_doc_type', sql.Int, idDocType);
}
request.input('id_spec', sql.Int, idSpec);
request.input('flag', sql.Int, flag);
request.input('redo', sql.Int, 1);
request.input('id_inventory', sql.Int, id_inventory);

request.execute("create_json").then(function(result) {
    var size = result.recordset.length;
    return Promise.all(result.recordset.map(function(element) {

            savePath = element['path'];
            idItem = element['id_item'];
            saveFilename = element['filename'];
            options = { "format": "A4", "orientation": element['orientation'], "renderDelay": "undefined", "border": "10mm" }
            idPatient = element['id_patient'];
            htmlFile = element['id_template'];
            var fillTemplate = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                files.push(basePath + element['path'] + separator + element['filename']);
                if (element['json'] != "") {
                    fs.readFile('templates' + separator + element['id_template'] + '.html', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            return console.log(err);
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        html = data;
                       // filling the template
                        resolve(html);
                    });
                }
            });
            var makeDirectory = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (element['json'] != "") {
                    mkdirp(basePath + element['path'], function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        resolve(element);
                    });
                }
            });

            var makePDF = (html) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    if (element['json'] != "") {
                        pdf.create(html, options).toFile(basePath + element['path'] + separator + element['filename'], function(err, res) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                reject(err);
                            } else {                                   
                                var request2 = new sql.Request();
                                request2.input('flag', sql.Int, 5);
                                request2.input('id_inventory', sql.Int, element['id_item']);
                                request2.execute("PDF_create_json", (err2, result2) => {});                                    
                            }

                            if (mergeNeeded == 1) {
                                if ((files.length > 100) || (files.length == size)) {
                                    PDFMerge(files, { output: basePath + mergedName }).then(() => {
                                        files.length = 0;
                                        files.push(basePath + mergedName);
                                        return "OK";
                                    })
                                }
                            } resolve("OK");
                        });
                    } else {

                        if (mergeNeeded == 1) {
                            if ((files.length > 100) || (files.length == size)) {
                                PDFMerge(files, { output: basePath + mergedName }).then(() => {
                                    files.length = 0;
                                    files.push(basePath + mergedName);
                                    return "OK";
                                })
                            }
                            console.log("mergedname: " + mergedName);
                            console.log("Files have been merged");
                            resolve("OK");
                        }
                    }

                });
            };
            return makeDirectory
                .then(() => {
                    return fillTemplate
                })
                .then(makePDF)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(files);
                })
        }

    ))
}).then(results => {
    res.end("all done");
})
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch your control flow. Yes, you are creating promises but are not waiting for them to be complete. You could use `async/await` sync or a Promise library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com)

The root problem of your particular code snippet is `result.recordset.forEach(element => {`, which, basically, runs synchronously and then calls `res.end()`

Either you can make everything `async/await`, but you might need to Promisify that `request.execute("create_json", callback)` call.

Or you can use a Promise library to do something like

```
Promise.each(result.recordset, function returnAPromise(){
  // your stuff here. Make sure this returns a Promise (chain)
})
.then(results => { 
  // now call res.end() 
})
```

to make sure everything in your array is processed first. (You'll also want to `catch` that promise chain with `res.error()` or whatever the call is, and be sure that your Promises return so they are chained successfully:

```
return makeDirectory.then(() => {
            return fillTemplate.then(result => {
                return makePDF(result).then(() => {
                     console.log("");
                });
            });
        });
```

Or to consolidate

```
return makeDirectory
.then(() => {
   return fillTemplate
})
.then(makePDF)
.then(() => { console.log('here') } )
```

These are just a starting point, but hopefully you find it helpful.

Comment: I've tried to follow your guide, but now have a problem, it fills the array of files[], including all rows returned from the stored procedure. Checks of files.length > 100 fails. I've obviously missed something. Made an edit to the original post

Comment: I am having a hard time following too! Check that `makePDF()`, resolve('ok') is different than, and not waiting for, that return 'ok'. I would suggest you add many console.log lines throughout your code, and run with only 1 or 2 files. See how your code is executing, and view every value as it processes, especially the start of every '.then()' and entrance into every function.. That will let you see what is really going on. Hope you get it working.